# How to install Joomla Over Xampp?

Tags: windows, downloads, joomla

I have installed the Xampp and started all the necessary task are done i have successful install of a Xampp. But How do I copy now my download Joomla Folder Like Usually done in windows same thing we can do also Ubuntu. So I think It's Possible But need a Push> anyone can help with this It will be Great help.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/19007/134333/Joomla_3.2.1-Stable-Full_Package.zip

extrack zip file in a folder and locate it in xampp/htdocs/ directory.

Run your apache and mysql services. on your browser open localhost/(direcoryname) the installation will begin.

Fill all the information Click on Next.

Give the database information it's not need to create a database. it will automatically create database (Fill all information). Click on Next.

There is no need to give the information about ftp. (If you need then give the your ftp information). Click on Next.

After that the finalization tab will be active for installation your joomla in xampp. Click on Install for installation.

Now your installation will be complete. Then it say to remove the installation folder (removed it.) and you are ready to access your joomla on your pc.

Comment: OK, I follow the step but When I press Remove Folder It says Access Denied?

Comment: I think you don't have permission on your joomla folder. go to your administrator user and remove and rename your folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy it to the root of your server, which should be in:

```
/var/www/
```

Comment: And fix permissions. E.g. `chown -Rv <user>:www-data /var/www`.